# XML & Xquery to retrieve and display output

Tags: xml, xquery

I thought XQuery is as same as SQL query but I found XQuery is quite complicated to understand.
I would like to find all libraries with same number of books available and as many as empty shelves as the library called "Oxford".

```
<librarycollections>
<library>
<id>1</id>
<library_name> oxford <library_name>
<name>DBMS</name>
<availble_books>2</availble_books>
<empty_shelves>5</empty_shelves>
</library>
```

```
for $x in doc("filename.xml")/librarycollections/library/
where $x/@available_books = available_books and $x/empty_shelves ="oxford"
return...
```

The result I'm trying to get is like this :

```
Empty shelves/number of books/ library name
```

```
<li>2 empty, 8 bookes @ Greenwich library </li>
<li>5 empty, 8 bookes @ UCL library </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, XQuery is to XML what SQL is to database tables. W3Schools maintains a great [XQuery tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_intro.asp).

How is this conditional expression:

```
for $x in doc("filename.xml")/librarycollections/library/
return if ($x/@library_name="oxford" and $x/available_books=2 and $x/empty_shelves=5)
then <library_name>{data($x/library_name)}</library_name>
else ()
```

Comment: thx for your reply.However this expression will not return the equal number of books found in all libraries neither the number of empty shelves as the ibrary oxford.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the format suggested by the xml (your xquery has '@', which is for attributes, where you have an element in the xml), try something like this, in two steps:

Find the 'oxford' library record:

```
let $oxford := doc("filename.xml")/librarycollections/library[library_name = "oxford"]
```

Then use that to find the matching library records (same number of books and at least as many empty shelves, skipping the oxford record itself):

```
return
for $x in doc("filename.xml")/librarycollections/library[id != $oxford/id and available_books = $oxford/available_books and empty_shelves >= $oxford/empty_shelves]
    (: format the results, using the variable from the for :)
    return <li>{$x/empty_shelves/text()} empty, {$x/available_books/text()} books @ {$x/library_name/text()} </li>
```

This uses xpath to do the selection, rather than using a where clause, but the where would work as well.